# Is there a way to check if two values in separate "columns" are equal?

Tags: database, mongodb

For example, with this data:

```
{id: 1, fname: "Barry", lname: "Sullivan"}

{id: 2, fname: "Sarah", lname: "Bailey"}

{id: 3, fname: "Drake", lname: "Barry"}
```

Is there a way, with a single query, that I could check to see if anyone had the same lname as id: 1 fname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to run two separate queries and get the result as one document. This will give you two separate arrays: 1-element with `id:1` and the other documents. Then you can simply run [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to get matching `lnames`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            first: [ { $match: { id: 1 } } ],
            others: [ { $match: { $expr: { $ne: [ "$id", 1 ] } }  } ]
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$first"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            matches: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$others",
                    cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.lname", "$first.lname" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y4mkr9CJZwZ)